# How to pass multiple values to insert statement from dynamic number of html textboxs?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I am doing a project in which as per number getting by GET method, I display dynamic number of  HTML Textbox for storing Multiple values. I am giving each textbox unique name+id in ascending manner starting from 1(Like textbox1,textbox2). Now I want that when I click on submit button, it should fire an insert statement which insert all textbox values at once. I know I can do by array, but my question is that how to get all textbox's value in an array and How to perform insert statement?

**I have done following code:**

Here is PHP Code for submit button:

```
 $schedules = array();
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        for($d=1; $d<=$_GET['totalDay'] ;$d++)
        {
            array_push($schedules,$_POST['txtSchedule'.'$d']);
        }
        print_r($schedules);
    }
```

Here is the html code:

```
<form method="post">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>Schedule</td>
 </tr>
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['tour_code']) and ($_GET['totalDay']!=1))
  {
    $tour_code = $_GET['tour_code'];
    $total = $_GET['totalDay'];

    $i=0;
    do
    {
      $i=$i+1;
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
    <td>
      <input name="txtSchedule<?php echo $i;?>" type="text"  size="30"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
      $start = date('Y-m-j',strtotime($start.'+1 days'));
  }while($i!=$total);
  }
  ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Tour Details" />
```

**But I am getting an empty array.**
Note: $total is coming through URLString's $GET method.

Below is the output of HTML:
[image]

Comment: @dbf: I have put all dynamic textbox with unique id, and I am trying to get it by $_POST method, but it's not working...

Comment: go for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020011/how-to-register-user-form-with-all-dynamic-fields-name-in-php/43135280#43135280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing first. You have an error, you can't use

```
array_push($schedules,$_POST['txtSchedule'.'$d']);
```

You must use DOUBLE QUOTES on the $d (single quotes won't evaluate d, it will literally read "txtSchedule$d" with a dollar sign, and not actually 0, 1,..., n)

```
array_push($schedules,$_POST['txtSchedule'."$d"]);
//or no quotes at all
array_push($schedules,$_POST['txtSchedule'.$d]);
```

(that may sovlve your problems)

---

But now let's get to how to make an array available to the $_POST object in the processing page via form naming conventions

You're not using array syntax, but you are oh-so close. In PHP, whatever is submitted needs to be of an expected format, and iterating txtSchedule0, txtSchedule1, ...txtScheduleN is not an Array(), but $_POST[] is an array that contains each (given what you've named your input fields, which is missing 1 small thing - square brackets).

What you need to do is be naming your inputs as an array is the array name followed by square brackets (arrayName[]), here is how you create an input array of the name txtSchedule (that way when you print_r($_POST['txtSchedule']) you get an Array())

```
<input name="txtSchedule[<?php echo $i;?>]" type="text"  size="30"/>
```

I had the same issue when I started in PHP, you were forgetting the square brackets around [<?php echo $i;?>]

Just make sure that if you want to do an iteration over an array of inputs:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['txtSchedule']); $i++){
    echo "They entered " . $_POST['txtSchedule'][$i] . " in the $i" . "th position";  
}
```

... you have used the <input name="arrayName[$i]"> sytax, or even more simply <input name="arrayName[]"> for it to auto-magically generate an array on submit in the order the inputs were in the HTML page. The naming convention is so important, and since you have it wrong (you used arrayName0, arrayName1, ... arrayNameN instead of arrayName[0], arrayName[1], ... arrayName[n]), it will never be available to you as an array.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. It works for me. Thanks a lot. And now for insertion, do I have to iterate insertion loop to add all textbox value at once?

Comment: What does your insert look like? If you are only doing a few rows at a time into your MySQL database, it won't hurt much to just do each insert in a separate Insert statement. Use the @Roonaan's answer below, he says it right. He's assuming you are inserting N columns into a table that has N-columns. The way MySQL knows which column is which is by order. But if you want to be safe, just modify the query to be from sql = "INSERT INTO 'myTable'..." to sql = "INSERT INTO 'myTable'(col1, col2, ..., colN)..."

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly you are trying to retrive user input from each textbox and save it in an array?
if so I would use jquery to select all textboxes and loop through them and retrive the value

Comment: can't I use $_POST method to get all values of all textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking purely at the SQL syntax, then you can just append extra records to insert at the end of your query by providing more value sets:

`INSERT INTO myTable (fieldName1, fieldName2) values ("Value1A", "Value1B"), ("Value2A", "Value2B")`

If you looking at the PHP logic, then my first suggestion is to use the http POST method instead of GET. Then start with processing the `$_POST` fields:

```
$data= array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if (preg_match('/^TextBox\d+$/', $key)) {
    $data[] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
  }
}
```

The construct the SQL query based on the available data

```
if (count($data) > 0) {
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO `myTable` VALUES("' . implode('"),("', $data).'")';

  // log query

  // execute query

  // process query results

  // redirect user to a thankyou page
  header('Location: thankyou.php');
}
```

Note that the code assumes that you have a mysqli connection instance available at `$mysqli`

Comment: Hey I have just a question will this insert query work = multiple insert query? I mean u r just passing values, Then how sql will figure it out that for which column all this values are passing? In my case, suppose I am adding 3 hobbies, then in table there must be pass 3 records which enters 3 hobbies...

Comment: I don't know what your table structure looks like. You can construct any query you like. You could use $sql = 'INSERT INTO `hobbies` (name) VALUES( ... );

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but should give you at least a start..

```
  String []ar=request.getParameterValues("name");
     String cmd=request.getParameter("cmd");
     if(cmd==null) cmd=""; 
     if(cmd.equals("Submit")){
     for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
      insert logic;

 <form method="post" action="page3.jsp">
 <br/><input type="text" name="name"/>
 <br/><input type="text" name="name"/>
 <br/><input type="text" name="name"/>

 <br/> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="cmd"/>
 </form>
```

Orignal post http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/197777/insert-dynamic-textbox-value-in-database

Comment: I agree with @Keshav you will surely need some JQuery to do this